# MySQL Query Question

Tags: mysql, database

Say I have the following 3 tables:

```
users
id : int 11 primary autoinc
email : varchar 255

tags
id : int 11 primary autoinc
name : varchar 255

tag_union
id : int 11 primary autoinc
tag_id : int 11
target_id : int 11
target_type : enum( 'user','blog','other' )
```

If I'm given a list of tags, say 1,3, and 8, I can select all of the users that have a union of **ANY** of the tags like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM `users`
WHERE `id` IN( SELECT `target_id`
               FROM `tag_union`
               WHERE `tag_id` IN( '1','3','8')
                 && `target_type`=='user' )
```

But how would I select only users that have a union for **ALL** 3 of the tags? I can't seem to think of a way to do this in a single query.

P.S. Sorry for the crappy title, someone can rename it if they can think of a more fitting one.

Comment: How many rows do you have in each table? Is performance an issue here?

Comment: @Mark: Currently the users table is max 50K rows, and the tag table ~2k, with the union being somewhere in the middle. Most people have only like one or tag.

Comment: I suspect that with 50K rows in the user tables the `IN` will take several seconds or more, whereas the JOIN will be almost instant. But if I'm wrong about that, I'd like to know so that I can learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your derived table should use a GROUP BY / HAVING:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE id IN
(
    SELECT target_id
    FROM tag_union
    WHERE tag_id IN ('1', '3', '8') AND target_type = 'user'
    GROUP BY target_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
)
```

Note that in MySQL the IN clause can be very slow. It might be better to use a join instead.

```
SELECT *
FROM users T1
JOIN
(
    SELECT target_id
    FROM tag_union
    WHERE tag_id IN ('1', '3', '8') AND target_type = 'user'
    GROUP BY target_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
) T2
ON T1.id = T2.target_id
```

I'm also assuming that `(target_type, tag_id)` is unique in the `tag_union` table.

Comment: It isn't distinct, a tag can be on multiple types, and a type can have multiple tags

Comment: @Josh: From your reply, I think you may have misunderstood what it means for a tuple to be distinct. I know the same tag can appear on multiple *different* types, but can the same tag appear on a *single* type (e.g. user) multiple times? And if it can, why is that necessary in your design?

Comment: No, it can't, sorry I misunderstood.

Comment: @Josh: Sorry that I missed the GROUP BY in my answer before. I fixed that now.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM `users`
WHERE `id` IN( SELECT `target_id`
               FROM `tag_union`
               WHERE `tag_id` IN ('1','3','8')
                 AND `target_type`='user' 
               GROUP BY `target_id`
               HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `tag_id`) = 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it with the group by/having approach the other suggested. But just for completeness, it can also be done with joins.

```
select u.id
      ,u.other_columns
  from users u
  join tag_union t1 on(u.id = t1.target_id)
  join tag_union t2 on(u.id = t2.target_id)
  join tag_union t3 on(u.id = t3.target_id)
 where t1.target_type = 'user' and t1.tag_id = 1
   and t2.target_type = 'user' and t2.tag_id = 3
   and t3.target_type = 'user' and t3.tag_id = 8;
```